# Split the line using delimiter and a string in one line for a bunch of rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

MAP Mumbai, (delhi,punjab) Location Hindu_college is having all_branches/facilites
MAP Banglore, (Kerala,Tamilnadu) Location sathyabama_university is having all_branches/facilites

Desired Output:
MAP:   Place.            Location
Mumbai  (Delhi,punjab)   Hindu College.

`s = df["columnnname"].str.split(",", expand=True).stack().str.split("(", expand=True).str.split('Location', expand=True)`

Getting  `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'. Tried this too **`df["columnnname"].to_string()** but still the same error. can some one help?

Comment: make multiple lines out of that, you will notice that some operations return a dataframe not a series, and `.str` is only accessible for series.

Comment: Tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: share a sample of your data, how the df looks like exactly